# Not able to create an MFA enabled Single Page Application in Auth0 using Terraform

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, terraform, auth0

I am trying to create a single-page application in Auth0 using Terraform but it is throwing me an error called Error: 400 Bad Request: Invalid grant types: mfa.

MFA grant type should be enabled into the Auth0 Applicaiton.

```
resource "auth0_client" "auth0_ui_client" {
  name                = "auth0_ui_client"
  app_type            = "spa"
  callbacks           = ["http://localhost:3000/callback"]
  allowed_logout_urls = ["http://localhost:3000/logout"]
  allowed_origins     = ["http://localhost:3000"]
  grant_types         = ["authorization_code", "implicit", "refresh_token", "mfa"]
}
```

Able to create the app in auth0 if I remove mfa from the grant_types but I need to create it with MFA.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyPPb.png)

I can create application manually directly in the auth0 and enable MFA grant type but the same is not happening while creating the application through terraform.